# CloudFormation change set chokes on empty CodeUri: in SAM templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

If this is invalid CloudFormation templating then someone should tell the engineer that wrote this blog post: [Managing Lambda@Edge and CloudFront deployments by using a CI/CD pipeline | Networking & Content Delivery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/managing-lambdaedge-and-cloudfront-deployments-by-using-a-ci-cd-pipeline/)

I'm using that template to deploy successfully.

But I want to use change sets to have safer deploys.

When I try to create a change set CloudFormation tells me CodeUri is missing:

> Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Resource with id [LambdaEdgeFunctionSample] is invalid. Either 'InlineCode' or 'CodeUri' must be set

This template deploys without issue.

Also I don't think I can use the sam commands for this ([A simpler deployment experience with AWS SAM CLI | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/a-simpler-deployment-experience-with-aws-sam-cli/)) because the lambda function is only a small part of this CloudFormation template.

When trying a different CodeURI I can see it demands an s3 URL:
`Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Resource with id [MyFunction] is invalid. 'CodeUri' is not a valid S3 Uri of the form \"s3://bucket/key\" with optional versionId query parameter.`

Answer (score 0):

For the template in the first article, If you remove the line 'CodeUri:' the template should deploy successfully. It seems to be complaining cause the line is empty.

If you are looking for a simple template to kick off a sam project, take a look at this one https://github.com/healthbridgeltd/nodejs-sam-bootstrap

It has a make file with multiple targets that makes your life easier.